# Java Calendar return month name genitive case

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get months names in a my android application.
This is my code:

```
public static String getMonthString(Calendar calendar) {
    return DateFormat.format("MMMM", calendar.getTime()).toString();
}
```

Main trouble is that example return names in **genitive case** if set russian device language. Instead that i need get names in a **nominative case.**

```
"Январь" instead "Января"
"Февраль" instead "Февраля"
"Март" instead "Марта"
```

If I set english language code works fine.

```
"Janyary"
"Fabryary"
etc
```

Is someone can help me? How to get correct names?

Comment: instead of DateFormat.format you can use calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.LONG, Locale.US)

Comment: H Raval, I tried calendar.getDisplayName(). If current language is russian this method return genetive case names. It's not work for me. After that i use Joda library. And problem still exist. I think it is android platform spec. I no ideas.

Comment: The question is outdated. All possible ways to solve this kind of problem were discussed in question: [Proper Russian month string translation Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642720/proper-russian-month-string-translation-java).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use Java 8, you should use `"LLLL"` instead of `"MMMM"`.
To get what you want, with first letter capitalized, you can use this code:

`String month = new SimpleDateFormat("LLLL",Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
month = month.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + month.substring(1);`