# What's wrong with Java date parsing code?

Tags: java, date, parsing, localization, java-time

This Java code:

```
LocalDate.parse("12 Сен 2018", DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(new Locale("ru", "RUS")).ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy"));
```

leads to the

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '12 Сен 2018' could not be parsed at index 3
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
```

Tried all of [Proper Russian month string translation Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642720/proper-russian-month-string-translation-java) examples - no result.

What's wrong with this code ?

*Note: I'm using Java 8*

***Upd:***
Tried this on local machine and in online compiler - in online compiler works in local machine - came error.

```
    Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1L, "Янв");
    map.put(2L, "Фев");
    map.put(3L, "Мар");
    map.put(4L, "Апр");
    map.put(5L, "Май");
    map.put(6L, "Июн");
    map.put(7L, "Июл");
    map.put(8L, "Авг");
    map.put(9L, "Cен");
    map.put(10L, "Окт");
    map.put(11L, "Ноя");
    map.put(12L, "Дек");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("dd ")
            .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, map)
            .appendPattern(" yyyy")
            .toFormatter(new Locale("ru", "RU"));       
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("12 Cен 2018", formatter));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper Russian month string translation Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642720/proper-russian-month-string-translation-java)

Comment: Java seems to what to use `сент` not `Сен`

Comment: @MadProgrammer, tried, same result

Comment: @CodeMatrix, it’s a relevant link, thanks for providing it, but this question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to create a custom formatter for this, which is not that complicated (first time knowing russian, become handy answering a stackoverflow question):

```
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1L, "янв");
    map.put(2L, "фев");
    map.put(3L, "мар");
    map.put(4L, "апр");
    map.put(5L, "май");
    map.put(6L, "июн");
    map.put(7L, "июл");
    map.put(8L, "авг");
    map.put(9L, "сен");
    map.put(10L, "окт");
    map.put(11L, "ноя");
    map.put(12L, "дек");
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("dd ")
            .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, map)
            .appendPattern(" yyyy")
            .toFormatter(new Locale("ru"));

 System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("12 сен 2018", fmt)); // 2018-09-12
```

Comment: Why should I do that ? Isn't code from my question must be able to parse such date format ?

Comment: @Artsiom as you have already seen, the answer to your question is "No". I don't know what else to say to you

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

**First**, `ofPattern` simply creates a pattern-based formatter, therefore discarding the locale:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                 .withLocale(new Locale("ru", "RUS"))
                 .ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy") // <------ static method!!
```

`ofPattern` is a static method that simply creates a new `DateTimeFormatter` instance (see below for a correct way to build it)

---

**Second**: the short month name seems incorrect for the pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
                 .withLocale(new Locale("ru", "RUS"))
.format(LocalDate.of(2018, 9, 12))
```

Results in `"12 сент. 2018"`. Java expects `сент.`, not `сен`.

This works and returns `2018-09-12`:

```
LocalDate.parse("12 сент. 2018", 
         DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
         .withLocale(new Locale("ru", "RUS")))
```

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for the feedback. I'll let this post just answer the OP's question directly. But I see your answer gives a solution in the current context...

Comment: While it may not give the solution that the OP wants, it’s the best explained answer (+1).

Comment: On my Java 8 I get `12 сен 2018`. On Java 9 and 10: `12 сент. 2018`. The difference must have to do with default locale data switching from Java’s own to CLDR in Java 9. In any case, the asker may not have the second issue if (and as long as) s/he is using Java 8 (or explicitly using COMPAT locale data).

Comment: About **First** - so how the to create formatter and parse such date values as '13 Сен 2018' ?

Comment: @Artsiom I've included a different, correct way in the second section (`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy").withLocale(new Locale("ru", "RUS"))`)

Comment: @ernest_k
`LocalDate.parse("12 Сен 2018", 
         DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
         .withLocale(new Locale("ru", "RUS")));` - could not be parsed at index 3

Comment: @Artsiom Yes, please see the second part of my post, or use a customer format as suggested by Eugene

Comment: @ernest_k I tried Eugene's approach and updated question

Answer (score 1):

Hi use this piece of Code :

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("ru", "RU");
    String pattern = "dd MMM yyyy";
    String date = "03 сен 2017";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, locale);
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    System.out.println(localDate);
```

Comment: yes I try and work well, can you share your error?@Eugene

Comment: @MohammadRezaSamadi I guess you tried it in java-8, my bad. I was running that in java-9/10/11 and it does not work

Comment: @Eugene yes I'm using java-8.