# How to get the date in Russian

Tags: kotlin

Tell me how to properly serialize the date `2020-07-27T04:28:06.000Z` and get the date in Russian in the format `27 июля 2020 04:28:06`?
In Java documentation is not localization `ru`

```
class CustomDateAdapter : JsonAdapter<Date>() {
    private val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(SERVER_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault())
    
    @FromJson
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Date? {
        return try {
            val dateAsString = reader.nextString()
            dateFormat.parse(dateAsString)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }

    @ToJson
    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Date?) {
        if (value != null) {
            writer.value(value.toString())
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val SERVER_FORMAT = ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642720/proper-russian-month-string-translation-java does this help?

Comment: No. This also gives no result and returns null `val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale("ru", "RU"));`

Answer (score 0):

Please try next code:

```
try {
    val dateParser = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    val date = dateParser.parse("2020-07-27T04:28:06.000Z")
    val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale("ru"))
    // or you can try (when calling 'format()' it will print "27 июля 2020 г. 04:28:06":
    // val dateFormatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale("ru"))
    val formattedDate = dateFormatter.format(date!!) // 27 июля 2020 04:28:06
} catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: It works. Also gives me the desired result: 
`val fd = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(edata)` `val fdata: String = DateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.LONG, Locale("ru")).format(fd)`.
But it doesn't work in my class `CustomDateAdapter`. Can you tell me how to implement this in the class itself?